# how to check I/O utilization of a process in Linux using commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to know the i/o utilization of every process using commands.

like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXHIN.png)

Comment: Use the `iotop` command.It is available in most Linux distros. You can install it  by `sudo apt-get install iotop -y`

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor disk I/O for processes with

- iotop
- htop
- btrace

Also you can get the I/O per process using `/proc/<PID>/io`:

```
[home ~]# cat /proc/24328/io
rchar: 5532416
wchar: 67578
syscr: 6548
syscw: 249
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 20480
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

Comment: In addition, use sysstat to monitor these statistics over time.